# deleting a item from sqlite db is not working - all items are being removed

Tags: android

Im doing a basic android app to learn about sqlite. The app have a itemfragment.xml that has 2 textviews to show the title of the produt and the price, so the layout of the app is like:

```
Pencil    1
Pen       1.20
...
```

And its possible to click in a add button that shows a new fragment where we can fill a editext for the title and other editext for the price to register a new note. This part is working fine.

Its also possible to click in a item of the list of products to delete it. This part is not working correctly. Im using cursorloader so the db operations are done in background. But Im getting a issue:

- When the user clicks in a item the item is not removed from the list, but if I close and open again the app all items of the list have been removed.

Do you know where is the issue? Why the fragmentlist is not updated by removing the clicked item after click in the item and why all items are being removed?

**// to list the products and the respective price**

```
public class ProductsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  private static final String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {
      Provider.Products._ID, Provider.Products.TITLE,
      Provider.Products.PRICE };

      private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;


  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, DBHelper.ALL_COLUMNS,
            null,null,null,null);
    String[] from = {DBHelper.TITLE, DBHelper.PRICE};
    int[] to = {R.id.title, R.id.price};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

  }
```

// **to delete a product**

```
@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id), null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + id + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

**// cursorloader methods**

```
 @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  }


 @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
  }


public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
  }
```

**// Provider class delete method:**

```
 @Override
  public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    int count=db.getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE, where, whereArgs);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url, null);

    return(count);
  }
```

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/price"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Full ProductsFragment:**

```
public class ConstantsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, DatabaseHelper.ALL_COLUMNS,
            null,null,null,null);
    String[] from = {DatabaseHelper.TITLE, DatabaseHelper.VALUE};
    int[] to = {R.id.title, R.id.value};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.add) {
      add();
      return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    AlertDialog dlg=(AlertDialog)dialog;
    EditText title=(EditText)dlg.findViewById(R.id.title);
    EditText value=(EditText)dlg.findViewById(R.id.value);

    values.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title.getText().toString());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.VALUE, value.getText().toString());

 getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, values);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id), null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item id " + id + "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private void add() {
    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_title).setView(addView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, this)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();
  }

  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  }

  public void insertNote(String title, Double value){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.VALUE, value);

    Uri noteUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Inserted" + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
  }


  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
  }


}
```

Comment: That's what `DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE any_positive_integer` does

Comment: It's not clear at all what `whereArgs` are, but I suspect they're broken.

Comment: Thanks. But in the provider there is the where:   int count=db.getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE, where, whereArgs); and then in then to delete there is the valueOf(id):  getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id), null);

Comment: and what you pass as where? and what as whereArgs?  again ... That's what `DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE any_positive_integer` does(deletes all items)

Comment: Its not the String.v‌​alueOf(id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id), null);
```

which results in the SQL `DELETE FROM table_name where **INTEGER**`.

If the integer is 0, it means false, otherwise it means true. So it deletes all items from the table.

You should use:

```
getActivity().getContentResolver()
    .delete(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

I am not sure whether you should use `_id=?` or `id=?`, try both.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with _id=?.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)